# Number length in mysql

Tags: mysql

Since it's not possible to set a minimum length of variable in mysql, how could I check in the trigger if the added number value has, for example, 11 digits.  I was trying to do it in this way

```
    delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER  OnInsert BEFORE INSERT on 'klient'
declare err varchar(40);
if char_length(CAST(NEW.Phone AS CHAR(10)) < 9 THEN
set err = "zly nr telefonu";
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err;
end if;
if char_length(CAST(NEW.Kod AS CHAR(6))) < 5 THEN
set err = "zly kod pocztowy";
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err;
end if;
if NEW.nr < 1 THEN
set err = "zly nr domu";
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err;
end if;
if char_length(CAST(NEW.Pesel AS CHAR(12))) < 11 THEN
set err = "zly nr pesel";
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err;
end if;
//
delimiter ;
```

But it throws an error.

Comment: What datatype are you using for your `Phone` column?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''klient' declare err varchar(40); if char_length(CAST(NEW.Telefon AS CHAR(10' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT ON user
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   DECLARE numLength INT;
   SET numLength = (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.Phone));

   IF (numLength < 9) THEN
     SET NEW.col = 1/0 ;/*--or some thing else **/
   END IF;

END;
```

Comment: What that `1/0` supposed to do?

Comment: It is just an example, what operation he need he can perform here

Comment: is 'for each row begin' needed if i'm only  checking length of new data ?

Comment: Yes when you insert a new record you need to check length of that

Comment: Do not use `LENGTH` - this will fail for multi-byte strings

Comment: Added CAHR_LENGTH for this.

Comment: @AbdulManaf Isn't it `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `CAHR_LENGTH`?